# instead of using two methods which looks like exactly the same, how could I extract generic parameters(one is List[T], another is generic T)

Tags: scala, generics

I have two methods which does almost the same thing, the method signatures are here:

```scala
def setProperty[T: TypeTag](name: String, value: T): Unit
```

```scala
def setProperty[T: TypeTag](name: String, value: List[T]): Unit
```

I can only declare two methods because I want to capture the List's generic parameter, which the first method can not. **And I want value to be exactly List instance instead of generic T** . how can I merge these two methods into one?

Comment: I don't quite understand, what's wrong with the signature of the second method?

Comment: @MichaelZajac Nothing wrong, I just want to merge two methods into one, since their code quite the same. the only diference is one need to extract list generic parameter which another doesn't need :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, ADTs are the way to go in this case

```scala
sealed trait Value[T]

case class Single[T](value: T) extends Value[T]

case class Multiple[T](values: List[T]) extends Value[T]

def setProperty[T: TypeTag](name: String, value: Value[T]): Unit = value match {
  case Single(value) => ...
  case Multiple(values) => ...
}
```